# Getting a success message only if and only data is inserted into Microsoft SQL server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, file-upload, system.net.mail

here is my challenge. I have successfully created a form that when a user fills and submits he/she gets a success message into their email inbox. But now my challenge is this whenever the submit button is triggered and even though data is not inserted into the database they still get the success message. I don't know what i got wrong in my coding. Please help. Here is my C# code:

```
public bool InsertRegistration()
    {
        // Determine the currently logged on user's UserId

        MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
        Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

        //Start of Upload 1
        FileUpload img = (FileUpload)AdmissionUpload;
        Byte[] imgByte = null;
        if (img.HasFile && img.PostedFile != null)
        {
            //To create a PostedFile
            HttpPostedFile File1 = AdmissionUpload.PostedFile;

            //Create byte Array with file len
            imgByte = new Byte[File1.ContentLength];

            //Get content type
            string contenttype = File1.ContentType;

            //Get file name
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(File1.FileName);

            //force the control to load data in array
            File1.InputStream.Read(imgByte, 0, File1.ContentLength);
        }

        FileUpload img1 = (FileUpload)StudentIDUpload;
        Byte[] imgByte1 = null;
        if (img1.HasFile && img1.PostedFile != null)
        {
            //To create a PostedFile
            HttpPostedFile File2 = StudentIDUpload.PostedFile;

            //Create byte Array with file len
            imgByte1 = new Byte[File2.ContentLength];

            //Get content type
            string contenttype1 = File2.ContentType;

            //Get file name
            string filename1 = Path.GetFileName(File2.FileName);

            //force the control to load data in array
            File2.InputStream.Read(imgByte1, 0, File2.ContentLength);
        }

        FileUpload img2 = (FileUpload)TranscriptUpload;
        Byte[] imgByte2 = null;
        if (img2.HasFile && img2.PostedFile != null)
        {
            //To create a PostedFile
            HttpPostedFile File3 = TranscriptUpload.PostedFile;

            //Create byte Array with file len
            imgByte2 = new Byte[File3.ContentLength];

            //Get content type
            string contenttype2 = File3.ContentType;

            //Get file name
            string filename2 = Path.GetFileName(File3.FileName);

            //force the control to load data in array
            File3.InputStream.Read(imgByte2, 0, File3.ContentLength);
        }

        FileUpload img3 = (FileUpload)PassportUpload;
        Byte[] imgByte3 = null;
        if (img3.HasFile && img3.PostedFile != null)
        {
            //To create a PostedFile
            HttpPostedFile File4 = TranscriptUpload.PostedFile;

            //Create byte Array with file len
            imgByte3 = new Byte[File4.ContentLength];

            //Get content type
            string contenttype3 = File4.ContentType;

            //Get file name
            string filename3 = Path.GetFileName(File4.FileName);


            //force the control to load data in array
            File4.InputStream.Read(imgByte3, 0, File4.ContentLength);
        }


        //SqlDateTime sqldatenull;

        using (var con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            using (var com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Candidates(FirstName, MiddleName, Surname, DateOfBirth, Phone, Email, DateApplied, CurrentLevel, MatricNo, JAMBNo, UTMEScore, YearOfAdmission, ExpectedYearOfGraduation, NIN, StudyMode, EntryMode, NextOfKin, NextOfKinEmail, NextOfKinPhone, RelationToNextOfKin, AcademicReferee,  AcademicRefereeMobile, RelationWithAcademicReferee,  DirectEntryRegNo, DirectEntryGrade, CurrentGPA, Courseid, Institution, HeadOfDept, HODPhone, HODEmail, RelatedToGovtOfficial, GovtOfficialName, PositionOfGovtOfficial, OnScholarship, ScholarshipName, YearOfScholarship, StateID, LGID, Community, AccountNo, SortCode, UType, AdmissionLetter, AdmissionLetterFileName, AdmissionImageType, StudentID, StudentIDFileName, StudentImageType, Transcript, TranscriptFileName, TranscriptImageType, Passport,  PassportFileName, PassportImageType, Maths, Eng, Subject3, Subject4, Subject5, Subject6, Subject7, Address, FacultyID, GradeSubject3, GradeSubject4, GradeSubject5, GradeSubject6, GradeSubject7, Location, UserId, StateOfResidence, Gender, Bank) VALUES (@FirstName, @MiddleName, @Surname, @DateOfBirth, @Phone, @Email, @DateApplied, @CurrentLevel, @MatricNo, @JAMBNo, @UTMEScore, @YearOfAdmission, @ExpectedYearOfGraduation, @NIN, @StudyMode, @EntryMode, @NextOfKin, @NextOfKinEmail, @NextOfKinPhone, @RelationToNextOfKin, @AcademicReferee,  @AcademicRefereeMobile, @RelationWithAcademicReferee,  @DirectEntryRegNo, @DirectEntryGrade, @CurrentGPA, @Courseid, @Institution, @HeadOfDept, @HODPhone, @HODEmail, @RelatedToGovtOfficial, @GovtOfficialName, @PositionOfGovtOfficial, @OnScholarship, @ScholarshipName, @YearOfScholarship, @StateID, @LGID, @Community, @AccountNo, @SortCode, @UType, @AdmissionLetter, @AdmissionLetterFileName, @AdmissionImageType, @StudentID, @StudentIDFileName, @StudentImageType,  @Transcript, @TranscriptFileName, @TranscriptImageType, @Passport,  @PassportFileName, @PassportImageType, @Maths, @Eng, @Subject3, @Subject4, @Subject5, @Subject6, @Subject7, @Address, @FacultyID, @GradeSubject3, @GradeSubject4, @GradeSubject5, @GradeSubject6, @GradeSubject7, @Location, @UserId, @StateOfResidence, @Gender, @Bank"))
            {
                com.Connection = con;

                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFN.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", txtMN.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtLN.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `smtpClient.Send(msg);` before `InsertRegistration();` so you are sending the email; then trying to insert the data in the database.

You might also want to return `bool` from `InsertRegistration();` as @Rahul has suggested above.

Not sure where you open the connection though you do close it; so if you open it in the method but wrap it in a `using` you can skip out the Close method (as the using will close it) so:

```
public bool InsertRegistration()
{
    // ...
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(...))
    {
        using (var com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Candidates..."))
        {
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFN.Text);
            // ... etc

            con.Open(); // open connection here, just before executing
            // return the true/false for whether a row was inserted
            return com.ExecuteNonQuery() >= 1;
        }
    }
}

protected void btnsendmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/Account/RegMessage.html")))
    {
        // ...

        if (InsertRegistration())
        {
            // Only run if inserted correclty
            smtpClient.Send(msg);
            lblMessage.Text = "Application submitted successfully! ...";
            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Error submitting application";
            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        lblMessage.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben Adams. I have formatted my code to accommodate all your suggestions but i am having an error message when trying to run the page:  Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0161: 'ORMApp_Scholarship_application.InsertRegistration()': not all code paths return a value

Comment: Ah you are doing an insert per file... You want to start the method with `bool inserted = false;` then change the `return com.ExecuteNonQuery() >= 1;` to `inserted &= (com.ExecuteNonQuery() >= 1);` and at the end of the method outside all the brackets; except last one `return inserted;`

Comment: The compiler doesn't know if any of the loops will run

Comment: It is cleared now only that i am getting the error: ConnectionString has not been initialised, I have edited my code

Comment: You've not added the `SqlConnection` to the `SqlCommand`. Either add it as second parameter on the constructor `var com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Candidates...", con)` or set it after `com.Connection = con;`

Comment: Thanks Ben: I am getting the error:  Incorrect syntax near '@Bank'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '@Bank'.

Source Error:

Comment: You don't close the `VALUES (` part of the Sql after `@Bank` inside the `"` quotes e.g. `@Bank)"), con)`

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteNonQuery` returns the no.of rows affected and thus you can change your method signature to return the same like

```
public int InsertRegistration() {
// all code 
int rows = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
return rows;
}
```

So in your event handler check for that and then show the message like

```
    int rows = InsertRegistration(); 
    if(rows > 0) {
    lblMessage.Visible = true;
    lblMessage.Text = "Application submitted successfully! C...";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. But this is my problem I want the users to only get a success email only when the data is inserted into the database. Right at the click of the submit button they still get a success email even when the data is not inserted into the database,

Answer (score 0):

First, i would suggest using the pattern Async Task to avoid dealocks somehow within your app. ( see the example below )

Second, as Ben said make the return of your method as boolean using the logic by Raul in his anwser:

So please, try this:

```
public async Task<bool> InsertRegistration() 
{
    // all code

    int rows = await com.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

    if(rows>0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

     protected void btnsendmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new 
     StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/Account/RegMessage.html")))
     {
        // ...

        if (InsertRegistration())
        {
            // Only run if inserted correclty
            smtpClient.Send(msg);
            lblMessage.Text = "Application submitted successfully! ...";
            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Error submitting application";
            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        lblMessage.Visible = true;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks BerBar. I still get a red underline under the InsertRegistration() saying not all code paths can return a value. How do i solve this. I have tried recoding but still showing

Comment: @Paschal, sorry for my delay. Could show me the part above of my demonstration, i meant, the //allcode ?